# Why in Selenium the command driver.find_element_by_xpath doesn't work?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to find and click an element with this command:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="address-book-entry-0"]/div[2]').click()
```

But it doesn't work.

For other buttons it's working, why for this it is not working?
Can you help me please?

Comment: You're not specifying whether it is the `find_element_by_xpath` that is failing or the `click` that is failing or what the URL is. You have to do provide more information.

Comment: where do i find this info? sorry I'm inexperienced :(

Comment: this is button link: https://www.amazon.it/gp/buy/addressselect/handlers/continue.html/ref=ox_shipaddress_ship_to_this_1?ie=UTF8&action=select-shipping&addressID=L2S2Z2YYKYCIIILC5J7IG120MUQQVSSOVA11VOSSVQQUM04PXTQ2EIA2OX64QLTI&enableDeliveryPreferences=1&fromAnywhere=0&numberOfDistinctItems=1&purchaseId=404-0800191-3916364&requestToken=&hasWorkingJavascript=1

Comment: If you got an exception, you should edit your question by copy and pasting the stacktrace of the exception into the question so that we may see it. You should also post enough of your code that reproduces the error.

Comment: i'have solved, sorry at all! I had entered a command before that did go in error! Tnx at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should show the relevant part of the HTML in order to be sure, but this behaviour could be caused by:

1. Wrong XPath.
2. The element is not clickable. You can wait until it is clickable. Check again that there is no other element on top of yours that will receive the click.
3. The element is in iframe. Switch to the iframe first.

If the suggestions above are not working for you, try to click the button [with JavaScript](https://www.guru99.com/execute-javascript-selenium-webdriver.html#7).

Comment: the strange thing is that before it worked then it didn't work anymore

Comment: Could it be dynamic?

Comment: It sounds like there was a change in the page. Dynamic, maybe yes, I have not seen the HTML.